# install PEAR on EasyPHP, error using transliterator

Tags: php, pear, pecl, easyphp

Something is making me crazy, I am using easyPHP 14.1 and I am getting this error message :

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function transliterator_transliterate()

so I try to install PEAR to use this sequence of steps :

- I create a folder `/pear` in `C:/ProgramFiles/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9/`
- I download `go-pear.phar` in `C:/ProgramFiles/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9/`
- I execute the file :

  - I did both system and local copy
  - I press Enter to accept all default locations
    (eg for "Installation base" : `C:/ProgramFiles/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9/`)
  - and then here I get a warning about "pear.bat" :

[image]

```
  - I click on PEAR_ENV.reg to update the registry
```

1. php.ini contain fine :

   include_path=".;C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\pear"
2. PATH in windows environment variables contain fine the value (automatically added) :
   C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9

I refresh the page that use a function with transliterator.

Result : still this PHP fatal error.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: installing pear doesn't install libraries. it just gives you the ABILITY to install pear libraries. did you actually install transliterator?

Comment: I also downloaded in /binaries/php/php_runningversion/ext a file I found (translit.dll) and I added it in php.ini (after other extensions) like this : extension=php_translit.dll, but nothing has changed... is it the right way to install transliterator? (if so, so why to install this pear before?) thank you for any advice..

Comment: @MarcB no idea Marc ?

Comment: just because you added a line to .ini doesn't mean it'll actually load. e.g. that dll was compiled for a different version of PHP or even with a DIFFERENT compiler. check the error logs and see what shows up.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I checked the error log and there is only "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function transliterator_transliterate() in..file.php", crazy

Comment: and I cared to take the dll for the right version of php I use (5.4 and "thread safe" ("ts") instead of "nts", otherwise it generated "php startup" popup with no other information, but with the dll "translit" for php 5.4 "ts", no problem.. except nothing works, really crazy

Comment: then the dll isn't being loaded. either it's not found, wrong version, or you modded the wrong .ini file. check `phpinfo()` - it'll tell which .ini files are being processed.

Comment: there are 2 things : Loaded Configuration File : "C:\Program Files\EasyPHP[..]\php.ini" (OK, the path I use since the beginning), and also :"Configuration File (php.ini) Path : C:\Windows", and here there is no php.ini in c:\windows.. even in hidden files, so which one is loaded?

Comment: I also found on https://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.php that php go-pear-phar doesn't work in Windows if there're spaces in the path, so I tried with a simple path (installing in c:/pear) but the same.. :(